# AngularJS Provider dependency injection - using $http in provider?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

#### tl;dr

I'm really struggling to find the appropriate pattern here. How should I best configure a generalized provider to a specific use-case? I can't use `$http` as a dependency in `.configure();` can I?

#### longer, boring explanation:

I am trying to create a generalized provider which I may reuse in Angular. I have it working, however it requires configuration.

The intention is to provide a fallback REST service to use in saving data to the server, but with provision to save offline in local-storage. Therefore, I need to provide appropriate `$http` calls for each instance of this provider.

Is it possible to provide appropriate `$http` calls with `.configure()` or else should I try and figure out how to inject `$http` into the provider from the start and then configure it afterward??

Answer (score 0):

It's frustrating... and may change in AngularJS 2.0... But for now, yes, it is not possible to do this. There is a very high wall between the `.configure()` and `.run()` states, so you can't access `$http` from a `.configure()` function. The reason is that it hasn't actually been created. At this stage, all that exists is the provider. Once all of the dependencies are configured, then the http provider will be used to make the real `$http` service.

I'm not sure **exactly** what you're trying to do, but there are two excellent AngularJS developers that are good to follow who have some advanced patterns in projects they've shared: Pascal Precht and Brian Ford. Here are two projects that make heavy use of provider/service concepts as well as $http-driven services:

- https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate
- https://github.com/btford/angular-modal

Angular Modal, especially, does $http work to load its templates. There might be use cases in there that are similar to what you're trying to do.